# Problems with cat 6 cable

Tags: ethernet, networking, cabling

Our company have all the networking with cat 5 cables. My problem is: one of our employees bought a cat 6 cable but we don't have any rj 45 for this cable, we only have for the cat 5. I tried so many times to insert it on the rj45 but always the last color(brown) doensn't fit, we use the T-568A. There's a way to fit it? It's almost fitting but when I managed to get all of them the last one doesnt fit.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't make too much sense. Mechanically, there's no difference between 8P8C aka RJ45 connectors for Cat 6 or Cat 5.

[edit after comments]
You might refer to *terminate* cabling - in that case, make sure that cables and panels/jacks match the same specifications. If they don't you can't do a clean job and may very likely produce unusable connections. You should consider hiring a professional for cable deployment. Also, make sure that your cabling gets certified properly. Makeshift terminations won't do.

Comment: That's true, but usually when you try to plug the rj45 for the cat 6 you need a support, right? I mean like a "guide" to insert the cable and then insert on the plug. So, it's it possible to crimp it?

Comment: There's a white tube that separates each string of the cable, so when I try to organize the cables and plug it, this white tube disturbs me

Comment: He's talking about *terminating* a cat6 cable. Yes, cat6 wires may be a bit bigger than old cat5, so it might take a few tried to get the wire into the crimp. Try different crimps. That "tube" is pair alignment guide; cut it off.